# Convert String to Size | Visual Basic

Tags: fonts, conversion, visual-basic

Using vb.
I'm trying to use the text of a combobox as the value of my font size.
Means, as a user, I can choose which font size I'd like to have by clicking it out of the dropdown menu.

Dropdown menu:

`Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("6")
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("10")
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("12")
    End Sub`

Now the chosen option should affect the font size. But therefore, I need to convert from string to size.
Anyone any help?

Also I could imagine there's a more efficient way to give a user the opportunity to change the font size. Any tips and advise is welcome!

Comment: Hi, What is it that you ant to change the font size of?  Is it all controls on a form (labels, buttons, text boxes etc)?  All controls of a specific type (all text boxes)?  A single input control (single text box)?

Comment: Hi, I just wanted it to affect one specific txtbox, like in your answer, exactly how it should work! Thanks alot!

Comment: Glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
    Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Your combo box should be built and populated when the form loads, not when the combo box is changed
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("6")
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("10")
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("12")

        ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 'This Auto-Selects the first entry to prevent you having to handle "null"'s
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim tryParseResult As Boolean 'holds the True/False for whether conversion to a number worked
        Dim parsedNumber As Integer 'Holds the number after conversion

        tryParseResult = Int32.TryParse(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, parsedNumber) 'try converting to number - "parsedNumber" will contain the number on success - "tryParseResult" will contain a true/false for success

        'If tryPArseResult = False - conversion failed - tell the user and stop.
        If tryParseResult = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("Conversion of " & ComboBox1.SelectedItem & " To Number Failed") 'Tell the user it failed
            Exit Sub 'Stop processing
        End If

        'Set TextBox1's Font to the same font with a new size
        TextBox1.Font = New Font(TextBox1.Font.Name, parsedNumber)

    End Sub
End Class
```

This should do the following:
[image]

If you want to do this ith multipler controls - you need to look at looping through controls in a form using `OfType` if you only want to work on certain controls